# Azure function is not always starting

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have 4 functions in app service triggered by timer.

They worked well for a few months, now app insights logs started to show this:
"One of function names" A lease ID was specified, but the lease for the blob has expired.
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException

Interval is 5 mins, sometimes the function starts, sometimes fails.
I have already changed storage account, it did not help.

Complete MS' stack trace is long, not sure if I should post it here.
It starts with Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException

They say here that I can see some hints in diagnostics:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-diagnostics

However it looks like those categories are only available in pure function app, not app service/web job in my case.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share stack trace without it can't  diagnose

Comment: Sorry, I already removed [SingleTone] from all functions, error is gone now. Behaves still the same, it displays 'Singletone lock aquired' when run locally, and I have to change hostid as before to try debugging.

Comment: In case if you are still facing the issue can you share the full stack trace along with the timeframe in UTC so we can review it at our end